# Android TabLayout - How do i achieve this tablayout indicator

Tags: android, android-tablayout, viewpagerindicator

I have a tab layout in my app, but I don't want the default tab indicator. I want something similar to the attached image. Please how do I achieve it. Thanks.

[Tab indicator I want to achieve (photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37NYm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use external libraries

Some libraries listed below :

**un-material-tab**

https://github.com/creageek/un-material-tab

**JSTabLayout**

https://github.com/honglei92/JSTabLayout

**MagicIndicator**

https://github.com/hackware1993/MagicIndicator

**FlycoTabLayout**

https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoTabLayout